# jQuery code won't run in content script of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just wondering if anyone had any input on why this code won't run in my content script for my chrome extension. The extension is setup properly, because I have code in the content script that DOES work, for some reason this code wont work at all. This code runs when I paste it into the console of the page that the code needs to run on.

Code:

```
function ucall(user) {
    window.open('test.com/userid=' + user, 'popup', 'width=600', 'height=600')
};
console.log("READY?")
var comments = document.getElementsByClassName('group-comments')[0]
console.log(comments)
$(comments).on('hover', '.wall-comment', function () {
    var user = $(this).find('a')[1].href;
    user = user.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); console.log(user);
    console.log("do you hover bro?")
    $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'yellow' });
    $(this).click(function () {
        ucall(user)
    })
});
```

My theory behind why it might not work was that i thought the div's declared in the variable "comments", weren't being loaded in time for the code to execute. 
So then i tried to do `$(comments).ready(function(){//code here})`; That still didnt work. I'm pretty stumped. Also, all the code in my content script is inside of a

```
$(document).ready(function(){// all content script code in here})
```

Comment: You have a typo probably? It should be `$(document).ready(function() { ...});`. Note that the `document` has to be converted to a jQuery object before chaining the ready method.

Comment: @Terry I just edited my original post, sorry about that it was a late night. My code is setup the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have added the code please check this..

```
function ucall(user) {
    window.open('test.com/userid=' + user, 'popup', 'width=600', 'height=600')
};
console.log("READY?")
// Here I have selected the first instance of the class using jQuery
var $comments = $('.group-comments').first();
console.log(comments)
//Used jQuery Instance directly.
$comments.on('hover', '.wall-comment', function () {
    var user = $(this).find('a')[1].href;
    user = user.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); console.log(user);
    console.log("do you hover bro?")
    $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'yellow' });
    $(this).click(function () {
        ucall(user)
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the code is able to console log $comments, but nothing happens for the hover event, not even the console log. However, if I try putting the code into the console of the page, it does work and run fine. It just wont run in my content script :\.

Comment: Can you show me the html? So I can find out the solution for you.